# Como descobrir o tamanho de um arquivo por plsql?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Olá, estou com dúvidas sobre como achar o tamanho do arquivo na linguagem PL/SQL.

Já procurei em vários lugares e achei essa solução como padrão:

```
declare
  vExists     BOOLEAN;
  vFileLength NUMBER;
  vBlocksize  NUMBER;
begin
  UTL_FILE.FGETATTR('directory_location',
                    'file.extension',
                    vExists,
                    vFileLength,
                    vBlocksize);
  dbms_output.put_line('vFileLength :' || vFileLength);
  dbms_output.put_line('vBlocksize :' || vBlocksize);
  dbms_output.put_line('MB :' || (vFileLength / 1000000));
end;
```

Mas ele me retorna null em todos os casos.

Alguém teria outra maneira de descobrir o tamanho de um arquivo em pl?

Obrigado desde já! :)

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, também gostaria de saber.

Comment: O que o Exists retornou ?

Comment: Basicamente é isso mesmo como está usando, vou postar a function que uso e não tenho problemas, talvez seu arquivo não está sendo encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que a função está correta, o problema pode estar relacionado ao caminho dos diretórios do arquivo, segue a função que uso para retornar o tamanho em bytes.

```
SELECT flength('diretorio_teste','teste.txt') size_in_bytes FROM dual;

-- Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flength(location_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                   file_in IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN PLS_INTEGER
IS 
    TYPE fgetattr_t IS RECORD (fexists BOOLEAN,
                               file_length PLS_INTEGER,
                               block_size PLS_INTEGER);
    fgetattr_rec fgetattr_t;
BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.fgetattr(location => location_in,
                      filename => file_in,
                      fexists  => fgetattr_rec.fexists,
    file_length => fgetattr_rec.file_length,
    block_size => fgetattr_rec.block_size);

    RETURN fgetattr_rec.file_length;
END flength;
/
```